# USB boot recently stopped working

Tags: boot-loader, live-usb, laptop

Not sure where to post this, so if I should move it somewhere else, please let me know.

I recently got a new laptop, **Dell Inspiron 7559** *i7 64 bit CPU*.

I stripped out the *Dell* stuff by reformatting the drive and installing a fresh copy of *Windows 10* I had available. *Windows* works fine on the *1TB* hybrid drive that came with the laptop (typing this on the *Windows* side now). I also installed a second drive in the *M.2* slot, a *275GB SSD*.

The next step in the plan was to install *Linux* on the extra drive as a dual boot as I do plenty of work in *Linux* as well. I used *Rufus* to make a *USB* boot drive about a week or so ago. *Ubuntu 16.04* if it helps.

I used the boot drive today and everything loaded fine, but I was having some trouble getting the partitions to work correctly and install *Linux*, so I rebooted the computer. Now, whenever I try to load from the *USB* stick it hangs on the *Ubuntu* splash screen. It does this even after redownloading the *ISO* of *16.04*, and *14.04* *Trusty* distributions using *Rufus* on the *USB* boot drive.

I hit *esc* to look at the boot loader, and it appears to get stuck in a cycle of soft-lockup *CPU#1* lockup for *22s*!  Just prior to that, it says it has an error and it can't access a memory region. I infer that it was trying to load the *OS* into Ram, and it hit a block of memory it couldn't access and hung.

I have slight *Linux* knowledge, but since I can't actually get into *Ubuntu* to run any commands I don't know what to do at this point.

I need *Linux* and at this point I'm down to using a *Mint VM*, which seems ridiculous given that I should be able to dual boot.

Thanks!